Can the W state, or any non-stabilizer state for that matter, be considered a magic state?
Some examples of magic states (these can all be found here): the $ |T\rangle $ state for implementing the $ T $ gate is
$$
 T | + \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + e^{i\pi/4}|1\rangle) 
$$
A $ |\text{CS}\rangle $ state for implementing the $ CS $ gate is
$$
 CS | + \rangle^{\otimes 2} 
= \frac{1}{2}  (|00\rangle +  |01\rangle  + |10\rangle +i |11\rangle) 
$$
A $ |\text{CCZ}\rangle $ state for implementing the $ CCZ $ gate is
$$
 CCZ | + \rangle^{\otimes 3} \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}(|000\rangle + |001\rangle + |010\rangle + |011\rangle + |100\rangle +  |101\rangle + |110\rangle - |111\rangle ) 
$$
A $|\text{Toffoli}\rangle $ state for implementing the Toffoli (also known as $ CCX $) gate is
$$
CCX | + \rangle^{\otimes 2} | 0 \rangle =  \frac{1}{2}  (|000\rangle +  |100\rangle  + |010\rangle + |111\rangle)
$$
It is well known that a magic state is always a non-stabilizer state. And indeed this is true for the above examples.
But is it true that every non-stabilizer state, for example the $ W $ state, is a magic state?

Isn't that known? Did you try a search?

Observation: It should be sufficient if you can answer this for $\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, since given any non-stabilizer state, you can prepare such a state from it (at least so it feels).

I think every single state that you listed is incorrectly defined, except the T state.

The question is what do you mean by "magic"? Usable in a state injection circuit? Distillable? Some people would call a state "magic" if it can be used for magic state distillation. In this context, there are (mixed) states outside of the stabilizer polytope which are "bound" and cannot be distilled. The precise region of qubit bound states is not known (to the best of my knowledge http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.030503).

@MarkusHeinrich I would think a good definition is "given a supply of that state, can it be used together with Cliffords to do universal quantum computation"? This seems like the weakest definition, at least if you only take the computational definition (i.e. solve BQP problems, not run general circuits).

@CraigGidney Ok fixed. Also since the gates $ T $, $ CCZ $ and $ CCX $ are all in the third level of the Clifford hierarchy I've now written the corresponding magic states in the classic gate teleportation-y form of "gate applied to some well chosen stabilizer state." What is the correct magic state for implementing a Hadamard gate? This question mentions the plus state https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/is-the-plus-state-a-magic-state-for-the-hadamard-gate ?

@IanGershonTeixeira Closer! The second "CCZ state" you define is still wrong. First, applying CCZ to ++0 does nothing so there'd be no minus sign. Second, the state with a minus sign that you did write down can be reach by a CZ gate so it's Clifford. You may have wanted a CS state?

@CraigGidney Ok I think I fixed it and now I have magic state for implementing  $ T, CS, CCZ, CCX $ all of which are in the third level of the Clifford hierarchy. What's the deal with magic states for implementing the Hadamard gate, say on the the $ [[15,1,3]] $ code to get a universal gate set. What is an example of a magic state to implement the Hadamard gate?

@IanGershonTeixeira A bell pair where you've applied the Hadamard gate to one of the qubits.

@NorbertSchuch that's essentially the definition of distillable states. If I'm not mistaken, all pure (non-stabilizer) states are distillable, at least for single-qubit states. EDIT: Well, at least distillable states have that property, there may be some subtleties in the other direction.

@CraigGidney Ah ok so a state for implementing the Hadamard gate is
$$
(I \otimes H) \frac{| 00 \rangle+ | 11 \rangle }{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{2}  (|00\rangle +  |01\rangle  + |10\rangle - |11\rangle)
$$
This is a stabilizer state since Hadamard gate is in the Clifford group. Would this state still be considered a magic state? Even though it is used to implement the Hadamard gate which is in the Clifford group?

@IanGershonTeixeira Eh I could go either way on that.

@MarkusHeinrich Distillable in which sense? As a magic state? (Do you have a resource, I didn't find sth upon a quick search.)

@NorbertSchuch Yes, in the sense of magic state distillation (say they can either be distilled into an H or T state). Campbell and Browne showed that one can resort to stabilizer protocols for m.s. distillation (http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0838); Reichard (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11128-005-7654-8) and Campbell and Browne (see ref above) showed tightness in certain directions (see also Fig. 1 in https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.030501). The remaining region of possibly bound states does not include any pure non-stabilizer states. However, this is for single qubit states.

@MarkusHeinrich Thanks. Do you know a reference for the claim that any pure non-stabilizer state is magic (in the sense that it enables universal QC)? After all, this would answer the question (at least in this sense).

@NorbertSchuch the above references only show this for single-qubit states. I am not aware of any paper showing this in the multi-qubit case (we should ask Earl this question). I would conjecture that the region of bound states always contains only mixed states, in any dimension ...
